# Printing arrays with objects in Java

Tags: arrays, object, playing-cards

First, I made a copy of the deck of cards. Then, I tried to use a method I created to print only the first seven cards of that copy deck (which I need to do 2 times). nextCard is a counter to keep track of where we are in the deck.

Here is my class:public class Deck

```
{
    private Card[] deck;
    private int nextCard;   


    public Deck(){
        deck = new Card[53];

        nextCard = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
            deck[i] = new Card(i);
            nextCard++;                 
        }

    }//Deck 

    public Deck(Deck existingDeck){//copy

        this.deck = new Card[52];

        for(int i=0; i < 52; i++){
            this.deck[i] = new Card(existingDeck.deck[i]);

        }
        nextCard++;
    }

    public void shuffle(){

        Card crdTemp = new Card();
        Random random = new Random();
        int num;
        nextCard = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
            num = random.nextInt (51);
            crdTemp = deck[i];
            deck[i] = deck[num];
            deck[num] = crdTemp;

            nextCard++;
        }
    }

    public Card dealACard(){
        Card crd = null;
        if(nextCard > -1){
        crd = deck[nextCard];
        nextCard--;
        }
        return crd;
    }

    public String dealAHand(int handSize){
        Card crd = null;
        String cards = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < handSize; i++){
            crd = dealACard();
            cards += crd.toString();
            //cards += dealACard().toString();
        }
        return cards;
    }

    public String toString(){

        String info = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
            deck[i].toString ( );
            info += deck[i];
            nextCard++;
        }
        return info;
    }

}
```

Then, in my driver:

```
Deck bDeck = new Deck(aDeck);
        bDeck.toString();
        String[] sevenCards = new String[bDeck];

        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
            System.out.println ("Copy deck: ");
            sevenCards[i] = bDeck.toString();

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
            System.out.println (sevenCards[i]);
        }


    }
```

I assume I am assigning the entire bDeck to each sevenCards array element, but I don't know how to do it differently. I also assume there is a way to do it without trying to create a new array like this, but again, I've gone through a lot of different ideas and nothing has panned out. Would really appreciate some direction, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I do understand you correctly, you want to print only the first seven cards of your deck? So you have to access the decks cards to do so:

```
    Deck bDeck = new Deck(aDeck);
    bDeck.toString();
    String[] sevenCards = new String[7];

    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        System.out.println ("Copy deck: ");
        sevenCards[i] = bDeck.deck[i];

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        System.out.println (sevenCards[i]);
    }


}
```

This will work if `Deck.deck` is accessible in your for loop and you properly implemented the `toString()` method of your `Card` class.

EDIT: Here are the final changes to `dealACard()`:

```
public Card dealACard(){
    Card crd = null;
    if(nextCard > 0) { 
      nextCard--;
      crd = deck[nextCard];
    }

    return crd;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, one of the requirements of this project is that the field be private: private Card[ ] deck; Any ideas? Thanks for the response. I can add the class above if it will help.

Comment: Jup, the complete class would help. If it is only about drawing 7 hand cards and it does not matter if the cards are drawn from the top or the bottom of the deck you could use `dealACard()` on the copy of the deck to do so. But I am not quite sure if i understand your situation correctly.

Comment: I'm about to add my class above, thanks! I tried dealACard(), but it gives me the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds and I can't figure out why.

Comment: I think you should put `nextCard++;` inside your for-loop in the copy-costructor of `Deck` and better initialize it with 0 before. If you fix this, your `dealAHand()` method should work as you expect.

Comment: I made the changes and I've been doing->                                                for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){   System.out.println(bDeck.dealACard());   but I still get the out of bounds at this line, and at crd = deck[nextCard]; from my Deck class.

Comment: I also realized it should be possible to use dealAHand which I had ignored before, but it's giving me out of bounds, too.

Comment: I think i finally figured it out. `nextCard` is 52 after the deck has been created. The `deck` array has 52 elements, so the last card is ´deck[51]´ as the first card is `deck[0]`. Thus, the first call to `dealACard()` fails, because `deck[52]` is out of bounds. If you change your if condition to `nextCard > 0` and put ´nextCard--´ before the array access, you should be fine.